# OSX: GLUT window never appears

Tags: c++, macos, sdl, glut, macports

I'm trying to run [ORTS](http://skatgame.net/mburo/orts/) on my Mac for a school project.  It was ostensibly written to be cross-platform, but I don't know if it was ever properly tested on OSX.  After a great deal of difficulty, I managed to get it to compile, but it still doesn't quite work.

When I run the `ortsg` application, which is the OpenGL graphical interface, the terminal output indicates that the game starts up, loads its assets and runs correctly.  However, the actual game window never appears.  The only possible indication of any problem is the following message:

> 2011-11-23 16:52:33.513 ortsg[4565:107] GLUT Warning: glutInit being called a second time.

Other than that message, all of the output is exactly the same as what I see when running on my school's Slackware Linux machines, where the game runs fine.  (Unfortunately it's rather inconvenient for me to do my work on those machines, hence my attempts to run it on OSX.)  I can get rid of that warning by commenting out a call to `glutInit` in `apps/ortsg/src/ortsg_main.C`, which doesn't seem to introduce any other problems, but the game window is still never shown.

I can't seem to find reports of anyone having similar problems on Google.  I don't expect anyone on SO will be intimately familiar with ORTS, so my questions are as follows:

1. Are there any common scenarios which might cause a GLUT window to not appear, particularly on OSX?
2. Does GLUT provide any facilities for debugging such problems?

Edit: As requested by JimN, here is some of the GLUT initialization code...

```
// From apps/ortsg/src/ortsg_main.C
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char mydir[81];
  getcwd(mydir, 80);
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  chdir(mydir);
  // ...
}

// From libs/gfxclient/src/GfxInit.C
void glutVisibilityDebug(int state)
{
  if(state == GLUT_VISIBLE)
    cout << "Window is visible" << endl;
  else if(state == GLUT_NOT_VISIBLE)
    cout << "Window is invisible" << endl;
  else
    cout << "Window state unknown";
}

void GfxModule::init_GLUT_window()
{
  cerr << "INITIALIZE GLUT WINDOW" << endl;
  GfxGlutAdaptor::set_client(this);

  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_ALPHA);

  // the window starts near the upper left corner of the screen
  glutInitWindowPosition(opt.win_x, opt.win_y);
  glutInitWindowSize(opt.win_w, opt.win_h);

  // Open a window
  glutCreateWindow(opt.title.c_str());

  // Register the splash as the draw routing until
  glutDisplayFunc   (GfxGlutAdaptor::splash);
  glutVisibilityFunc(glutVisibilityDebug);

  if (opt.full_screen) glutFullScreen();
}
```

I added the glutVisibilityDebug function to see if I could determine what GLUT thinks the window's visibility state is, but none of my debug statements are ever printed.  Something else just occurred to me which might help debug this.  I tried at one point to replace glutDisplayFunc with a function which just printed "glutDislplayFunc called" to stderr.  I noticed that the text was only printed when I quit the application.

Comment: You have to make sure that glutInit is called before any other call that might involve OpenGL stuff. Could you show us the GLUT initialization code please.

Comment: I have added the initialization code.  As you can see, glutInit is the third call in main, so it occurs well before any other OpenGL code.  Since glut thinks glutInit is being called twice on my Mac, I will see if I can determine where the second call is... perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: I've done some grepping and I cannot for the life of me find a second place where glutInit is being called.  Is it possible that something could be calling it automatically?

Comment: Are you calling glutPostRedisplay() at the end of your display function (in this case Gfx::GlutAdaptor::splash)?

Comment: Double-check how you're creating your application bundle.

Comment: @JimN: glutPostRedisplay() seems to have never been called anywhere in the code, but I added it to all of the display functions (splash, which shows the splash screen, and draw, which actually draws the game), as well as to the idle function - still no luck.  I compiled some GLUT skeleton code to make sure it wasn't a problem with my libraries, but the skeleton code worked fine.
genpfault: There is no application bundle.  It's just an executable being built with a Makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the [daily snapshot](https://skatgame.net/mburo/orts/src_snapshot/orts.tgz) from 26/11/2011, and then installed all dependencies using [brew](https://brew.sh/) on my Mac.

Executed `export OSTYPE=DARWIN` followed by `make init` and `make`. There were several compilation problems which I fixed on this **makefile**:

```
# $Id: makefile 10648 2011-10-06 15:46:07Z mburo $
#  
# This is an ORTS file (c) Michael Buro, licensed under the GPL

# This make file works for systems which use gcc
#
# - shell variable OSTYPE must be set in your shell rc file as follows:
# 
#   if LINUX matches uppercase($OSTYPE) => Linux
#   if DARWIN matches                   => Mac OS X
#   if CYGWIN matches                   => Cygwin (gcc on Windows)
#   if MSYS   matches                   => MinGW (gcc on Windows)
#
#   check that value with echo $OSTYPE and set it in your shell resource
#   file if above words don't match. Don't forget export OSTYPE when using sh or bash
#
#   I use:  OSTYPE=`uname`
#
# - ORTS_MTUNE = i686 athlon-xp pentium-m etc.
#     if set, -mtune=$(ORTS_MTUNE) is added to compiler options
#
# - set GCC_PRECOMP to 1 if you want to use precompiled header files (gcc >= 3.4)
#
# - adjust SDL/X paths if necessary
#
# - for non-gcc compilers try -DHAS_TYPEOF=0 if typeof causes trouble
#
# - make MDBG=1 ...    displays the entire compiler/linker invocation lines
#
# - make clean         removes make generated files
# - make cleanobj      removes all .o files
#
# - make [MODE=dbg]    compiles targets in debug mode (no STL debug!)
#
# - make MODE=opt      compiles with optimizations
#
# - make MODE=bp       compiles with bprof info
#
# - make MODE=gprof    compiles with gprof info
#
# - make MODE=stldbg   compiles optimized stl debug version
#
# - make <app>         creates application bin/<app>  (omit prefix bin/ !)
#                      use periods in <app> in place of slashes for applications
#                      within subdirectories (e.g. "make rtscomp06.game2.simtest")
#
# - make list          displays a list of all registered applications
#
# - make init          creates necessary dep+bin+obj directories and links
#
# - make               creates all applications
#
# - shell variable ORTS_MODE defines the default compile mode
#   if not set, the passed MODE= parameter or dbg will be used, if MODE is not passed
#   otherwise ORTS_MODE will be used
#
# issues: 
#
#  - all include files are used (only using library includes would be better)
#
# new:
#
# applications and libraries can now name their individual external library dependencies
# (libs + headers)     
# see: apps/*/src/app.mk and libs/*/src/lib.mk, esp. libs/gfxclient/src/lib.mk
#
# todo: adjust mac/cygwin to new libary setting


# supported substrings of OSTYPE
# The following words must be uppercase
# If they are found in the uppercased OSTYPE variable
# the particular O/S matches
OSTYPE_LINUX  := LINUX
OSTYPE_MAC    := DARWIN
OSTYPE_CYGWIN := CYGWIN
OSTYPE_MINGW  := MSYS

# convert OSTYPE to uppercase
OSTYPE := $(shell echo -n "$(OSTYPE)" | tr a-z A-Z )
#$(warning OSTYPE=$(OSTYPE))
#OSTYPE := LINUX

# -DOS_LINUX or -DOS_MAC or -DOS_CYGWIN is passed to g++
# also set: OS_LINUX, OS_CYGWIN, OS_MAC := 1 resp.
# MinGW uses OS_LINUX for now.

# tar file name
PROJ := orts

# directories to be excluded from snapshot tar file

# no longer needed SNAPSHOT_EXCLUDE := libs/mapabstr apps/mapabs apps/polypath apps/hpastar

# special targets
EXCL_INC := clean init cleanobj tar dep rmdeps list tar snapshot rpm

# libraries
#LIB_DIRS := kernel network serverclient gfxclient pathfind osl mapabstr path ortsnet ai/low dcdt/se dcdt/sr newpath
#LIB_DIRS := $(wildcard libs/*) libs/dcdt/se libs/dcdt/sr libs/ai/low
LIB_DIRS := $(wildcard libs/*/src) $(wildcard libs/*/*/src)
#$(warning LIBS $(LIB_DIRS))

# sub-projects
ifeq ("$(MAKECMDGOALS)","")
APP_DIRS := orts ortsg#  built by default (do not edit)
else
APP_DIRS := $(MAKECMDGOALS)# build the passed on application
endif

FILT := $(filter $(EXCL_INC),$(MAKECMDGOALS))

ifneq ("$(FILT)","")
APP_DIRS := 
endif

#MAKECMDGOALS := compile_gch link_gch $(MAKECMDGOALS)
#$(warning making $(MAKECMDGOALS) ...)

# $(warning making $(APP_DIRS) ...)

.PHONY: all ALWAYS $(EXCL_INC) $(APP_DIRS) init

# where dependencies are stored (change also in dependency command (***) below)
#
DEP := dep

#$(error $(vp))

# make libraries and applications, make and link gch file first
all: all_end

# create tar file of the entire project
tar:
    @ $(MAKE) clean; cd ..; tar cfz ../$(PROJ).tgz $(PROJ)


# daily SVN snapshot
SVNROOT=svn://mburo@bodo1.cs.ualberta.ca:/all/pubsoft
snapshot:
    rm -rf orts
    mkdir orts
    svn export $(SVNROOT)/orts/trunk orts/trunk
    tar cfz $(PROJ).tgz orts
    rm -rf orts
    rm -rf orts_data
    mkdir orts_data
    svn export $(SVNROOT)/orts_data/trunk orts_data/trunk
    tar cfz orts_data.tgz orts_data
    rm -rf orts_data

CC        := g++
CC_OPTS   := -pipe -felide-constructors -fstrict-aliasing -Wno-deprecated
# -fno-merge-constants

#WARN      := -Wall -W -Wundef 
WARN      := -Wall -W 
#-Wold-style-cast

#ifneq ("$(OSTYPE)", "$(OSTYPE_MINGW)") 
ifeq (,$(findstring $(OSTYPE_MINGW),$(OSTYPE)))
WARN += -Wundef 
endif 

OPT:=-O3

ifneq ("$(ORTS_MTUNE)","") 
  OPT:=$(OPT) -mtune=$(ORTS_MTUNE)
endif

OPT_FRAME := -fomit-frame-pointer 

# default 
AWK := gawk
EXE_SUFFIX :=

#ifeq ("$(OSTYPE)", "$(OSTYPE_MAC)") 
ifneq (,$(findstring $(OSTYPE_MAC),$(OSTYPE)))

################### Mac OS X 

OS_MAC := 1

MACROS    := -DGCC -DOS_MAC -DHAS_TYPEOF=1 -DTRANSFORM_MOUSE_Y=0 -DMAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=1040 -DTARGET_API_MAC_CARBON=1
USR_FRAME := /Library/Frameworks
SYS_FRAME := /System/Library/Frameworks
INC_OPTS += -I/usr/local/Cellar/sdl/1.2.14/include/SDL \
            -I/usr/local/Cellar/sdl_net/1.2.7/include/SDL \
            -I/usr/local/Cellar/glew/1.7.0/include/GL \
            -I/usr/include/GL \
            -L$(USR_FRAME) -L$(SYS_FRAME) -L/usr/local/Cellar/sdl/1.2.14/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/sdl_net/1.2.7/lib -L/usr/local/lib

SHARED_LIBS0 := -lc -lz  -lpthread \
               -lSDL \
               -lSDL_net \
               -lSDLmain \
               -framework Foundation \
               -framework AppKit

AWK := awk
#WARN += -Wno-long-double

ifeq ("$(CPU)", "G5")
OPT += -mcpu=970 -mpowerpc64
endif

else

################### MinGW

#ifeq ("$(OSTYPE)", "$(OSTYPE_MINGW)")
ifneq (,$(findstring $(OSTYPE_MINGW),$(OSTYPE)))

OS_LINUX := 1
MACROS   := -DOS_LINUX -DGCC -D_WIN32=1 -DTRANSFORM_MOUSE_Y=1 -DHAS_TYPEOF=1
MACROS   += -DGLUT_NO_LIB_PRAGMA -DGLUT_NO_WARNING_DISABLE
INC_OPTS += -I/mingw/include/GL -I/local/include 
SHARED_LIBS0  := -lm -lzlib1 -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_net -lpthreadGC2 -lstdc++

else

################### Linux | Cygwin

MACROS   := -DGCC -DTRANSFORM_MOUSE_Y=1 -DHAS_TYPEOF=1
INC_OPTS += -I$(HOME)/include -I$(HOME)/include/GL -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/SDL -I/usr/local/include/SDL -I$(HOME)/usr/local/include/GL
# -I/home/dsk06/cscrs/c399/c399-software/include

#ifeq ("$(OSTYPE)", "$(OSTYPE_LINUX)")
ifneq (,$(findstring $(OSTYPE_LINUX),$(OSTYPE)))

################### Linux 

OS_LINUX := 1
MACROS += -DOS_LINUX
#SHARED_LIBS0  += -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -lz -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_net -lpthread -lGL -lGLU -lXi -lXmu -lglut -lGLEW $(MODEL_LIBS) -lstdc++
#SHARED_LIBS0  += -L$(HOME)/lib -lm -lz -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_net -lpthread -lstdc++
SHARED_LIBS0  += -L$(HOME)/lib -lm -lz -lSDL -lSDL_net -lpthread -lstdc++
# -lefence

else 

#ifeq ("$(OSTYPE)", "$(OSTYPE_CYGWIN)")
ifneq (,$(findstring $(OSTYPE_CYGWIN),$(OSTYPE)))

################## Cygwin

OS_CYGWIN := 1
EXE_SUFFIX:=.exe
MACROS += -DOS_CYGWIN -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DGLUT_IS_PRESENT=1 
#-mno-cygwin
#INC_OPTS += -I/usr/include/mingw   -I/usr/include/mingw/GL -I/usr/include
#$(warning "INC_OPTS=" $(INC_OPTS))
# fixme: /lib/SDL_main.o -> -lSDLmain (didn't get SDL to compile on Cygwin)
# adjust paths if necessary
SHARED_LIBS0 := -lSDL -lSDL_net -lpthread  -lz -lstdc++ 

# GLEW not checked under cygwin!

else 

# unknown OSTYPE

$(error "!!!!! unknown OSTYPE=$(OSTYPE) !!!!")

endif
endif
endif
endif


# default mode; if ORTS_MODE set, use it
# otherwise use MODE if passed, or dbg otherwise

ifeq ("$(ORTS_MODE)", "") 
  MODE := dbg
else
  MODE := $(ORTS_MODE)
endif

OBJ_DIR := obj
CONFIG  := config

SHARED_PROF_LIBS := $(SHARED_LIBS0)
SHARED_BP_LIBS := ~/lib/bmon.o $(SHARED_LIBS0)

OBJ_OPT := $(OBJ_DIR)/opt
OBJ_DBG := $(OBJ_DIR)/dbg
OBJ_SDBG := $(OBJ_DIR)/stldbg
OBJ_PROF:= $(OBJ_DIR)/prof
OBJ_BP  := $(OBJ_DIR)/bp

OFLAGS  := $(WARN) $(OPT) $(OPT_FRAME) # !!! -g added for 2007 competition
DFLAGS  := $(WARN) -g -ggdb # -ftrapv
SDFLAGS := $(WARN) -g -ggdb -O -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG # STL debug mode is SLOW!
PFLAGS  := $(WARN) $(OPT) -pg -O
BPFLAGS := $(WARN) -g -ggdb -O2

ifeq ("$(MODE)", "opt")
  FLAGS := $(OFLAGS) -DNDEBUG -Wuninitialized 
#-DSCRIPT_DEBUG
  STRIP := strip
  OBJ   := $(OBJ_OPT)
  SHARED_LIBS := $(SHARED_LIBS0)
else 
  ifeq ("$(MODE)", "gprof")
  FLAGS := $(PFLAGS) -DNDEBUG -Wuninitialized
  STRIP := echo
  OBJ   := $(OBJ_PROF)
  SHARED_LIBS := $(SHARED_PROF_LIBS)
else 
  ifeq ("$(MODE)", "bp")
  FLAGS := $(BPFLAGS) -DNDEBUG -Wuninitialized
  STRIP := echo
  OBJ   := $(OBJ_BP)
  SHARED_LIBS := $(SHARED_BP_LIBS)
else 
  ifeq ("$(MODE)", "dbg")
  FLAGS := $(DFLAGS) 
  STRIP := echo
  OBJ   := $(OBJ_DBG)
  SHARED_LIBS := $(SHARED_LIBS0)
else
  ifeq ("$(MODE)", "stldbg")
  FLAGS := $(SDFLAGS) 
  STRIP := echo
  OBJ   := $(OBJ_SDBG)
  SHARED_LIBS := $(SHARED_LIBS0)
else 

# unknown MODE

$(error "!!!!! unknown MODE=$(MODE) !!!!")

endif
endif
endif
endif
endif

CCOPTS  = $(CC_OPTS) $(MACROS) $(FLAGS) $(INC_OPTS) -DBOOST_STRICT_CONFIG
# -m32  for 32-bit applications

LD      := $(CC) $(CCOPTS) 
LDOPTS  := $(FLAGS)


# line prefix

ifeq ("$(MDBG)", "") 
VERBOSE=@
else
VERBOSE=
endif

# how to generate precompiled header file if GCC_PRECOMP=1
# otherwise, create dummy file

ALLH       := All.H
ALLGCH     := $(ALLH).gch
ALLGCHMODE := $(ALLGCH).$(MODE)

ifeq ("$(GCC_PRECOMP)", "1")

$(CONFIG)/$(ALLGCHMODE) : $(CONFIG)/$(ALLH)
    @ rm -rf  $(CONFIG)/$(ALLGCH)
    @ echo "compile gch file"
    $(VERBOSE) $(CC) $(CCOPTS) -c -o xxx1 $<
    @ mv xxx1 $@
    @ echo "link gch file"
    $(VERBOSE) cd $(CONFIG); ln -sf $(ALLGCHMODE) $(ALLGCH)
else

$(CONFIG)/$(ALLGCHMODE) : $(CONFIG)/$(ALLH)
    @ echo "DUMMY GCH FILE"
    $(VERBOSE) touch $@

endif


# link gch file to gchmode file
# depends on compiled header file

ifeq ("$(GCC_PRECOMP)", "1")

link_gch: 
    @ echo "link gch file"
    $(VERBOSE) cd $(CONFIG); ln -sf $(ALLGCHMODE) $(ALLGCH)

else

link_gch:
    @ echo "remove gch file"
    @ cd config ; rm -f $(ALLGCHMODE) $(ALLGCH)
endif

#===================================================================

# how to create dependency files
# add depfile (.d) as dependent file
# (***) (can't use $(DEP) in sed command because it contains / - so if DEP changes edit this line!
# also prepend object path for .o file
#

DEP_EXEC = $(VERBOSE) set -e; $(CC) -MM $(CCOPTS) $(INC_OPTS) $< | sed 's/$*\.o[ :]*/$(subst /,.,$(basename $<)).o dep\/$(@F) : /g' | $(AWK) '{ if (index($$1,".o") > 0) { print "$$(OBJ)/" $$0 ; } else { print $$0; } }' > $@; [ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@OB

# how to compile source files
#

COMP_EXEC = $(VERBOSE) $(CC) $(CCOPTS) -c -o $@ `pwd`/$<

#-------------------------------------

define create_sublib_rules2
$$(OBJ)/libs.$(subst /,.,$1).src.%.o : libs/$1/src/%.$2
    @ echo "comp($$(MODE)):" $$<
    $$(COMP_EXEC)

$$(DEP)/libs.$(subst /,.,$1).src.%.d : libs/$1/src/%.$2
    @ echo dep: $$<
    $$(DEP_EXEC)
endef

define create_sublib_rules
$(foreach ext,C c cpp m,$(eval $(call create_sublib_rules2,$1,$(ext))))
endef

#-------------------------------------

define create_subapp_rules2
$$(OBJ)/apps.$1.src.%.o : apps/$(subst .,/,$1)/src/%.$2
    @ echo "comp($$(MODE)):" $$<
    $$(COMP_EXEC)

$$(DEP)/apps.$1.src.%.d : apps/$(subst .,/,$1)/src/%.$2
    @ echo dep: $$<
    $$(DEP_EXEC)
endef

define create_subapp_rules
$(foreach ext,C c cpp,$(eval $(call create_subapp_rules2,$1,$(ext))))
endef

#===================================================================

# collect all source files, replace suffix by .o, and filter out *_main.o

# input:  FILES
# output: O_FILES

define create_O_FILES
#FILES     := $$(notdir $$(FILES))
C_FILES   := $$(filter %.C, $$(FILES))
c_FILES   := $$(filter %.c, $$(FILES))
cpp_FILES := $$(filter %.cpp, $$(FILES))

m_FILES   := 
ifeq ("$(OSTYPE)","$(OSTYPE_MAC)")
#ifneq (,$(findstring $(OSTYPE_MAC),$(OSTYPE)))
m_FILES   := $$(filter %.m, $$(FILES))
endif

O_FILES   := $$(C_FILES:.C=.o) $$(c_FILES:.c=.o) $$(cpp_FILES:.cpp=.o) $$(m_FILES:.m=.o)
O_FILES   := $$(subst /,.,$$(O_FILES))

O_FILES := $$(filter-out %_main.o, $$(O_FILES))
endef


# include all applications and dependencies (uses SHARED_LIBS for linking)

APP_SDIRS := $(subst .,/,$(APP_DIRS))

ifneq ("$(APP_DIRS)","")
#include $(patsubst %, apps/%/src/app.mk, $(APP_DIRS))
include $(patsubst %, apps/%/src/app.mk, $(APP_SDIRS))
endif

#$(warning lib_dirs="$(LIB_DIRS)")

vp := $(patsubst %, apps/%/src, $(APP_SDIRS)) \
      $(patsubst %, libs/%/src, $(APP_LIBS)) \
#     $(LIB_DIRS)

#vp := $(patsubst %, %/src, $(LIB_DIRS)) \
#      $(patsubst %, apps/%/src, $(APP_DIRS)) 

INC_OPTS += -Iconfig $(addprefix -I, $(vp))

# new
INC_OPTS += $(LIB_EXT_HD) $(APP_EXT_HD)

# $(warning INC_OPTS= $(INC_OPTS))

# where source files are searched

#$(warning vp="$(vp)")

vpath %.C   $(vp)
vpath %.c   $(vp)
vpath %.cpp $(vp)
vpath %.m   $(vp)

all_end: link_gch $(APP_DIRS)

cleanobj:
    rm -f $(OBJ_OPT)/*
    rm -f $(OBJ_DBG)/*
    rm -f $(OBJ_SDBG)/*
    rm -f $(OBJ_PROF)/*
    rm -f $(OBJ_BP)/*

clean:
    ( rm -f bin/*; exit 0)
    rm -f $(DEP)/*
    rm -f $(OBJ_OPT)/*
    rm -f $(OBJ_DBG)/*
    rm -f $(OBJ_SDBG)/*
    rm -f $(OBJ_PROF)/*
    rm -f $(OBJ_BP)/*
    rm -f $(CONFIG)/*.gch*
    rm -rf misc/doxygen/html
    find . -name "*.bprof" -exec rm -f '{}' \;
    find . -name ".ui" -exec rm -f '{}'/* \;
    find . -name ".moc" -exec rm -f '{}'/* \;

rmdeps:
    @ rm -f $(DEP)/

rpm:
    cd misc/pkgs/fc7; ./makerpm; cd ../../..

# create dependency, object directories
# doesn't touch links (pointing to fast local partitions)
 
init:
    @ echo "create directories"
    @ config/create_dir bin
    @ config/create_dir $(DEP)
    @ config/create_dir $(OBJ_DIR)
    @ config/create_dir $(OBJ_OPT)
    @ config/create_dir $(OBJ_DBG)
    @ config/create_dir $(OBJ_SDBG)
    @ config/create_dir $(OBJ_PROF)
    @ config/create_dir $(OBJ_BP)
#   @ ln -s ../../orts_data/trunk orts_data
    @ (cd libs/pathfinding/dcdt; ./makelinks; exit 0) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Then some changes I had to do manually, to fix errors like:

```
sr_bv_math.cpp:561: error: ‘isnan’ was not declared in this scope
```

Edit the file `trunk/libs/pathfinding/dcdt/sr/src/sr_bv_math.cpp` and right after the cmath include, declare `isnan` as *extern*:

```
#include <cmath>
extern "C" int isnan(double);
```

That compiled the binaries, but then I had to also download `orts_data.tgz` to run the applications.

Well, running **ortsg** for the very first time failed, reporting:

texture size = 64X64

```
REMARK: can't open file:  testgame/ortsg/terrain.tga
REMARK: can't open file:  testgame/ortsg/noise.tga
Unable to load terrain noise texture testgame/ortsg/noise.tga
ERROR: /Users/karlphillip/installers/orts/orts/trunk/libs/gfxclient/src/GfxTerrain.C GfxTerrain() (line 213): failed to load noise image testgame/ortsg/noise.tga
REMARK: closing connection
REMARK: !!! already closed
REMARK: ~IO_Buffer called
```

Even though the files are there. So I KILLED the application and tried it again:

```
2011-11-27 01:51:02.947 ortsg[390:903] GLUT Warning: glutInit being called a second time.
seed=1322365862
ERROR: /Users/karlphillip/installers/orts/orts/trunk/libs/network/src/TCP_Client.C connect() (line 27): can't connect
REMARK: mixer not open
REMARK: closing connection
REMARK: !!! already closed

/Users/karlphillip/installers/orts/orts/trunk/libs/network/src/TCP_Client.C connect() (line 27): can't connect
Abort trap
```

The first line of the error might be familiar to you. Even though the app was killed, something seems to be left hanging somewhere, and **the only way I found to bypass the error** and have a clean run of the application was rebooting my computer.

It seems this application has issues on Mac OS X and need immediate fixing. I suggest you install a Linux VM, or even a Windows VM inside your Mac to be able to run **orts**, if you really have to use it.

Comment: Thanks for going to the effort of trying to get this to run.  To run ortsg, you first need to run an orts server in a separate terminal window.  So if you're in the trunk directory, open two windows and do: `bin/orts`, wait a few seconds, and then run `bin/ortsg`.  That should result in ortsg starting up, although I suspect you'll see the same result I do; that is, no GUI...  To kill them, I have to run `killall ortsg` in another window.  (orts will die when the client disconnects.)

Comment: The only way to fix what's happening is to dig deep into the code and patch it yourself (assuming you can find the problem). I think that installing a Virtual Machine at this point might be the best solution to your problem.

Comment: I think you're right... a VM is probably the way to go.  I was considering modifying the app to use SDL exclusively instead of SDL + GLUT, but I simply don't have time to do so.  I'm still perplexed as to why the GLUT window is never displayed, but getting my project finished is more important to me than figuring that out.  Thanks for the effort you put in to trying to help out!  I have awarded you the bounty.